# How to get the year from datepicker ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have code which the user choose date .

I need to to get the value year and put it in div.

How can I do that?

[jsFissl Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/d7PSX/)

many Thx.
the code:

```
<div class="demo">
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</div>
<div id="Year"></div>

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true

    });

       $("#Year").text($("#datepicker").val());
```

I try to use `.substring(0, 4)`but I don't kno how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows the year you wanted to extract.

HTML:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <div class="demo">
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    <button>Show year</button>
</div><!-- End demo -->
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });

    $("button").click(function() {
        var split = $("#datepicker").val().split('/');
        alert(split[2]);
    });
});​
```

The [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method of String class divides the string and returns as an array.

EDIT: This does everything you wanted.
Take a look at the [onSelect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) event.

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText) { 
            var split = $("#datepicker").val().split('/');
            $("#Year").text(split[2]);
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert that input value into a Javascript Date as well and have everything from it's method.

> http://jsbin.com/ugaxob/2/edit

```
$(".btn-getdate").click(function() {

  var dt = $("#datepicker").val(),
      d = new Date(dt);    

  $("#Year").text(d.getFullYear());

});
```

or **go wild** and use [**MomentJs**](http://momentjs.com/) plugin and you will get so much fun (live example updated)

---

When you want to perform something on a plugin, that is called **act upon an event**, and you should see the **Events tab** in the DatePicker, where you can find `onSelect`.

My live example was changed to act upon selection and no need to press any link or button.

Comment: you right and the next seloution correct but but how to display it without to press the button in the div

Comment: added event to the live example, please read the hole answer so you will know where to get help next time you need such thing :)

Comment: I would like to point you out a datepicker and a timepicker, that I prefer to work with as they play very well with [**Bootstrap Framework**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) (one of the most used CSS frameworks), the [**DatePicker**](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) and the [**TimePicker**](http://jdewit.github.com/bootstrap-timepicker/).

Answer (score 0):

How about this : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7PSX/12/)
 No need to do string manipulation, just create Date object using selected date from `datepicker` and use `getFullYear()` method to get selected year...

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({

       onSelect: function(date) {
        var d = new Date(date);
        alert(d.getFullYear());
       },
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true
    });

});
```