# Materialize css date input

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

How do I get the value of a date that I have selected from materialize css datepicker
Below is the code

```
<!--The Date Born-->
<div class="col s12 m6">
     <label for="Icon_date">Date Born</label>
     <input type="date" class="datepicker" id="datepicker">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xx3cjqek/1/)**

```
alert($('.datepicker').val());
```

This will alert the value of current date in the input via jQuery.

Just verify that if its correct showing value inside input or not via plugin like firebug for firefox or chrome developers tools for chrome because some times plugin don't show up the value in the input while show up in label or something else. Then you can get value by using [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) on each time value changes in that input field.

Note that if there is method natively in plugin use that and do not use this at all.

Comment: What if I want only the year to be alerted, What should I do ?

Comment: You can do it like `var dateString = $('.datepicker').val();
alert(dateString.slice(-4));` Also check updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xx3cjqek/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot . I needed that

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of the datepicker to a javascript variable.

```
var date = $('#datepicker').val();
```

Comment: What if I want only the year to be alerted, What should I do ?

Comment: this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328944/how-to-get-the-year-from-datepicker-ui

Answer (score 1):

```
var datePickerObject = $('#datepicker').pickadate().pickadate('picker')    
console.log(datePickerObject.get())
```

Create datepicker object when you create datepicker with javascript.

please check this link: 
http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-get-value

Answer (score 0):

download this library http://materializecss.com/bin/materialize-v0.97.3.zip
or

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>



  $('.datepicker').pickadate({
            selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
            selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
    $('#date').datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth:true,
        yearRange: '1980:2013', 
        dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year:selected").val();
            return [(day != 0), ''];
        }
    });
});

 </script>
```